# How to split a one column Data Frame into multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading a text file and it looks like this:

```
8 16
1 2 1.0
1 3 2.0
2 3 1.0
2 4 5.0
```

When I read this file, it's just a one column dataframe.
I want to remove the first row and split it into a dataframe with three columns, with headers 'f', 't', 'l':

```
   'f' 't' 'l' 
0   1   2   1.0
1   1   3   2.0
2   2   3   1.0
3   2   4   5.0
```

How could I manipulate this?

Comment: It would be better to read the txt in correct format than manipulating it later. try pd.read_fwf('your_txt') or pd.read_csv('your_txt', delim_whitespace= True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the use case for [`pandas.read_fwf()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html):

#### Code:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(data, skiprows=1, names='ftl')
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = StringIO('\n'.join([x.strip() for x in u"""
    8 16
    1 2 1.0
    1 3 2.0
    2 3 1.0
    2 4 5.0
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]))

df = pd.read_fwf(data, skiprows=1, names='ftl')
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
   f  t    l
0  1  2  1.0
1  1  3  2.0
2  2  3  1.0
3  2  4  5.0
```